# fieldset タグに対する An invalid form control with name='xxx' is not focusable. エラー

Tags: html5, google-chrome

Chrome で以下のフォームをサブミットすると、コンソール上に `An invalid form control with name='foo' is not focusable.` エラーが表示されました。
なぜ `fieldset` に対してこのエラーが出るのでしょうか？

```
<form name="test">
  <fieldset name="foo">
    <input type="text" name="bar" required="required">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg942g58/)

Comment: Chromeのバグだと思います。http://crbug.com/new から報告してみては。

Comment: 「なぜ」、に対する回答にはなりませんが、「novalidate」をつけると回避は出来るそうです。  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: `novalidate` だと必須チェック＆フォーカスされなくなりますね。ひとまず、バグ報告してエラーを無視するしかないですかね…。